# What is the Dojo 1.6 equivalent of jQuery(html)?

Tags: jquery, dom, dojo

In jQuery, you can easily create DOM nodes from raw HTML. This is especially useful when using templates.

What is the equivalent in Dojo?

(FYI:  I'm migrating something from jQuery to Dojo.  The raw HTML is generated from Underscore.js templates, and I'd like to avoid throwing them away.)

---

[UPDATE: 2012-01-19 7:17pm GMT+8]
As per @esailija 's comment, dojo.toDom is indeed the equivalent of jQuery(html) -- unfortunately, it's only been added to Dojo 1.7, while I'm kinda stuck with Dojo 1.6.  Updated the question to reflect the version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think perhaps what you are looking for is a combination of `dojo.place` and `dojo._toDom` (available without the underscore in >=1.7).

The `toDom` function takes the string and makes it into a DOM element or document fragment.

```
n = dojo._toDom("<li>foo</li>");             // n is a single DOM node
n = dojo._toDom("foo");                      // n is a DOM text node
n = dojo._toDom("<li>foo</li><li>bar</li>"); // n is a DOM document fragment
```

The `place` function also takes a string and a target.

```
dojo.place("<li>foo</li>", dojo.byId("baz")); // li element is added to 
                                              // element with id "baz"
dojo.place("<li>foo</li>", "baz");            // Same as above.
dojo.place("foo", "baz");                     // Note: Element with id "foo" 
                                              // is placed in element with
                                              // id "baz"
dojo.place(dojo._toDom("foo"), "baz");        // Text node "foo" is placed
                                              // in element with id "baz"
```

Notice the third example: if the string doesn't start with a `<`, it's treated as the id of an element somewhere else in the document.

Btw, the `dojo.place` function also takes a third position argument, which can be "first", "last", "replace", "before", "after" (and probably a few other things).

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/place.html

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about dojo._toDom() -- I almost needlessly ranted about Dojo missing a very useful feature. :p

Comment: @NikkiErwinRamirez NP. It was actually a dojo "private" (hence the leading underscore), but I think they realized it was something everyone used directly, so they made it "public" in 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the [create](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/create) method.

Comment: there is no `html` passed to `create`, it looks like the equivalent of `jQuery("<elemname>", props)` instead of `jQuery(html)` which are different overloads. So [toDom](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/toDom) is actually `jQuery(html)` and `create` is `jQuery("<elemname>", props )`.

Comment: dojo.toDom is indeed the equivalent of jQuery(html) -- unfortunately, it's only been added to Dojo 1.7, while I'm kinda stuck with Dojo 1.6

Comment: In dojo < 1.7 it's `dojo._toDom`, I believe. You could also check out `dojo.place` ( http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/place.html )